# Issue with combining weighted data log histograms

Tags: version-10, histograms, logarithmic-scale

I have a bit of a strange problem. I'd like to overlay 3 different logarithmic Histograms with two of them stacked and one separate [*]. Without  weights the solution is simple:

```
data1 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1, 3], 10^3];
data2 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[5, 3], 10^3];
data3 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[10, 3], 10^3];
Show[Histogram[{data1, data2}, ChartLayout -> "Stacked", ScalingFunctions -> {None, "Log"}],Histogram[data3, ChartStyle -> Red, ScalingFunctions -> {None, "Log"}]]
```

However, this doesn't look nice when I have weighted data and I can't figure out a way to fix it. The issue is that Mathematica doesn't know where to end the histogram of data1 and data2. I tried the following:

```
data1 = WeightedData[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1, 3], 10^3], Table[1, {i, 1, 10^3}]];
data2 = WeightedData[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[5, 3], 10^3], Table[1, {i, 1, 10^3}]];
data3 = WeightedData[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[10, 3], 10^3], Table[0.1, {i, 1, 10^3}]];

Show[Histogram[{data1, data2}, ChartLayout -> "Stacked", ScalingFunctions -> {None, "Log"}], Histogram[data3, ChartStyle -> Red, ScalingFunctions -> {None, "Log"}]]
```

which gives,

$\hspace{3cm}$[image]

Swapping which histogram is first in *Show* makes things worse and playing with *PlotRange* was also no use.

[*] I emphasize that I'd like two of this histograms stacked because I think one can put all the histograms in a single Histogram function if this is not the case and there is no problem any more.

Comment: This must be a Version 10.0.0 /10.0.1 issue; your code works as expected  in Version 9 (Windows 8 64bit). If it is, perhaps it should have the version tag?

Comment: @kguler: My version is indeed 10.0.0. I updated the tag.

Comment: The issue remains in version 10.0.1.0.

Comment: The issue remains in version 10.0.2; Can someone please check in 10.1.0, so to tag this as a bug (isn't it?). Also, does anyone know if this has been reported to WR? This problem also happens, for a single Histogram, where we enter a specific plot range.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even the uneweighted data can have display (offset) problems when using Show. Also the data3 histogram obscures portions of the stacked histogram.

```
SeedRandom[500];

data1 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1, 3], 10^3];
data2 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[5, 3], 10^3];
data3 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[10, 3], 10^3];

Show[
 Histogram[{data1, data2},
  ChartLayout -> "Stacked",
  ScalingFunctions -> {None, "Log"}],
 Histogram[data3,
  ChartStyle -> Red,
  ScalingFunctions -> {None, "Log"}],
 Frame -> True, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

Create the stacked histogram data manually and use a single `Histogram`

```
data12 = Join[data1, data2]; (* stacked data *)

Histogram[{data12, data1, data3},
 ScalingFunctions -> {None, "Log"},
 Frame -> True, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

```
data1w = WeightedData[
   RandomVariate[
    NormalDistribution[1, 3], 10^3],
   Table[1, {10^3}]];
data2w = WeightedData[
   RandomVariate[
    NormalDistribution[5, 3], 10^3],
   Table[1, {10^3}]];
data3w = WeightedData[
   RandomVariate[
    NormalDistribution[10, 3], 10^3],
   Table[0.1, {10^3}]];
```

Similarly for the weighted data

```
data12w = WeightedData[
   Join[data1w[[2, 1]], data2w[[2, 1]]],
   Join[data1w[[2, 2]], data2w[[2, 2]]]];
(* stacked data *)

Histogram[{data12w, data1w, data3w},
 ScalingFunctions -> {None, "Log"}]
```

[image]